# Disable opening tabs when specific web page is opened using javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to disable opening new tabs when users are on my website. is it possible using javascript?
Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815239/disable-opening-new-window-or-new-tab-by-holding-down-on-a-link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815239/disable-opening-new-window-or-new-tab-by-holding-down-on-a-link)

Comment: now that question is on holding down links. i want to disable users to open new tab on browser and go to my website again. i have set some values in session variables so it affects my website process. so i cannot let users to go to my website again using opening new tab

Comment: You cannot prevent default browser behaviour like opening a tab using javascript.

Comment: then what should i do to stop users opening a new tab and go to my website again while my website is also open in another tab?

Comment: You would probably have to change the way you work with session variables. For us to be able to help you further we need more information.

Comment: solved it by myself using session key ID. Thank You for trying to help me.