# Is there any way to disable the context menu options like open in new tab and open in new window in browser using javascirpt

Tags: javascript, c#, browser

I know this question has been already asked and answered but I am not able to get exact solution what I require. Actually I want to either disable this option or I don't want to allow browser to open a new window neither blank nor  with content. Also I don't want to remove HREF from the  tags in my html.Any kind of guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You could disable the context menu *entirely*, if you wanted, not sure if just removing particular options is possible

Comment: The question is, why do you want to do that?

Comment: Sounds like you have forced**ad's** on your page that you don't want to open but those force ads will be in the agreements of you getting something for free... Also you are in an agreement so I wouldn't recommend stopping them "If this is the situation"

Comment: Actually its a client requirement and the application is behaving differently if opened in new tab on any link. Also my question is this possible any how?

Comment: Also I don't to hide context menu fully as some options like copy paste are required.

Comment: @Mubashir please create a working example of what you are dealing with. Having source code to a problem is always helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @NewToJS Actually I need this behavior through out the application ... So not a particular scenario... please take this question in a generic way

Comment: Hi, @Mubashir, see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815239/disable-opening-new-window-or-new-tab-by-holding-down-on-a-link and this other https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22642056/JAVASCRIPT-Disabling-Open-In-New-Tab.html